# Is it possible to send a friend request through Android Facebook API?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to create an Android app and I want to send a Facebook friend request through Android Facebook API. I have spent some time but couldn't find an interface for this. Is this possible to do this through Facebook API if I know the person's Facebook id?

Comment: I could get it to work as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372456/facebook-friends-dialog-returns-unknown-method-error/11818315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you use the Friends dialog: see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/ for details.